# Separate Nginx access log file for certain requests only

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, logging, blocking, request

As far as I can see Nginx supports by default 2 log files: `error_log` (tracks issues related to the Nginx server itself) and `access_log` (tracks requests processed by Nginx). Whilst it is possible to control the format of `access_log` with the [`log_format`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule) directive, I have been unsuccessful at finding a way of logging only certain requests to a separate file, and therefore would like to ask the question on SF as a reference for future readers:

**Is there a way to log certain requests to a different log file than the one defined by `access_log`?**

FYI the reason behind this question is that I have a rule that denies access to unwanted crawlers with a 200 (because 403 would give them a hint that they're being blocked), and filtering those requests out of the `access_log` becomes more difficult.

Comment: nginx 1.7.0+ allows using an if condition in access_log directive itself. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25852578/2208271

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cjc` put me on the right track. Using `access_log` in an `if` statement by itself is not possible (You get a `nginx: [emerg] "access_log" directive is not allowed here` error). So the workaround is as follows:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (crawler) ) {
  set $crawler 'yes';
}
location ~ .* {
  if ($crawler = 'yes') {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/blockedbots.log;
    return 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, isn't this an access log inside an if statement..?

Comment: Yep, the [doc says that](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) you can use `Context: http, server, location, **if in location**, limit_except`

Answer (score 7):

access_log supports if:

(access_log path [format [buffer=size [flush=time]] [if=condition]];)

`access_log /var/.... if $crawler;`

Source:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Comment: This is the cleaner solution as of `NGINX 1.7.0`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, putting inside the if block was failing nginx syntax validation.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to put an `access_log` directive inside an `if` block, according to the documentation:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule

So, you should be able to do something like:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (crawler) ) {
   access_log /path/to/other/log/file ;
}
```

Comment: `access_log` inside `if` statement by itself isn't possible, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

When I came upon this post I was looking for a way to send AWS ELB healthcheck logs to a separate file as they were clogging up `access.log`.  I was never able to get `access_log` to work with `if` inside a `location` block, and this does not work either:

```
map $http_user_agent $healthcheck {
    "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" 1;
    default 0;
  }

access_log /var/log/nginx/elb-healthcheck.log main if=$healthcheck;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main if=!$healthcheck;
```

In a sea of braces it is easy to forget that the NGINX configuration file is not a programming language.

What I ended up with, albeit clunky looking, is this:

```
map $http_user_agent $not_elb {
    "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" 0;
    default 1;
}
map $http_user_agent $elb {
    "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" 1;
    default 0;
}

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main if=$not_elb;
access_log /var/log/nginx/elb-healthcheck.log main if=$elb;
```

Regular traffic goes to `access.log` and ELB healthcheck logs go to `elb-healthcheck.log`.