# nginx log when specific referrer is present

Tags: nginx, logging, log-files

Because someone steals content from our website, I need to create additional log file, that logs only if http_referrer contains specific domain.

Currently I have this:

```
   if ($http_referer ~* (bad-domain.com)){
           return  500;
   }
```

But instead of return 500, i need to return normal response, but to log the request.

Comment: Since 1.7.0 nginx's `access_log` has `if` parameter. See docs

Comment: Why do that at all instead of just greping the log for bad referers?

Answer (score 3):

The `access_log` directive is valid inside `if`, so you can simply add one there.

**However**, its presence overrides any ones that appear *above* it in the hierarchy, so if you simply add one entry the request will *not* be logged to whatever access log you normally log for that server.

To get around that, you can use *two* `access_log` directives inside the `if`, one which repeats the regular access log, and one for your special access log (which can also use a different `log_format` if you wish).

Answer (score 1):

Just putting **access_log** inside **if**, does not work

However **access_log** only inside **if** inside **location** and from this thread we can see the workaround:

[Separate Nginx access log file for certain requests only](https://serverfault.com/questions/394676/separate-nginx-access-log-file-for-certain-requests-only)

```
if ($http_referer ~* (bad-domain.com)){
  set $bad_domain 'yes';
}

location / {
  if ($bad_domain = 'yes') {
    access_log logs/bad_domain.log;
    return 200;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive like this

```
map $http_referer $loggable_referer {
    default           0;
    ~*bad-domain.com  1;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/bad_domain.log combined if=$loggable_referer;
```