# Catch backslashes, single and double quotes in GET requests

Tags: nginx, security, hacking

According to this [*SQL Injection Basics* article](https://www.hempstutorials.co.uk/sql-injection-basics/):

> <…> the operations mostly used for breaking\fuzzing the SQL query’s are.
>
> - `'` Single quote
> - `"` Double Quote
> - `\` Backslash (MySQL Escape character)

There also are hex-encoded characters (e.g. `0x3a3a`) sometimes.

I want to log and drop all requests containing those. Here's where I am so far:

```
set $susp 0;
if ($request_uri ~ "%27") {
  set $susp 1;
}
location ~ \.php {
    if ($susp = 1) {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/for-review.log;
        return 500;
    }
    # further fastcgi configuration
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

(I understand that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), but it [seemed necessary](https://serverfault.com/questions/394676/separate-nginx-access-log-file-for-certain-requests-only/394701#394701))

This fails to trigger on `/foo/ba'r`, but at least works fine on `/?foo=b'ar`. But that's it: the other characters I try aren't triggered either.

Here's what I've tried:

- [`$request_uri ~ "%27|%22"`](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142953#634097): single works, double doesn't
- `$request_uri ~ "%27|\""`: single works, double doesn't
- `$request_uri ~ "%27|0x"`: both work, but `0x` gets false positives on *thumb=230x240*

And I'm not even sure how do I approach the backslash.

Do you guys know how to make it work?

P.S. Thought about using [Amazon WAS](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/), but it requires another service (Cloudflare or load balancer) which I'm not yet ready for.

P.S. I realise that other measures need to be taken; this is supposed to drop those annoying GET scans. Also I doubt the legit visitors will end up having those while they're browsing. My logic was this: any barrier complicating the hack helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main `nginx.conf`, under `http {}`:

```
# set the variable
map "$request_uri" $susp {
    default 0;
    "~*(?<suspm>(\\x|%)(3c|3e|5c|22|27)+)" 1;
}
# match logging
log_format suspl '$remote_addr /$suspm/ - $remote_user $host [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_cookie"';
```

Individual virtual host configuration:

```
location / {
    if (\$susp = 1) {
        access_log /var/log/suspl.log suspl;
        return 403;
    }
    # etc…
}
```

Also,

> I doubt the legit visitors will end up having those while they're browsing

Heads up: turns out, they do carry something like `%7B%22` in their cookies set by some (not all) tracking/analytics software.